# Multiplication principle and permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, intuition

Definition of Multiplication principle in Principles and Techniques in combinatorics by Chuan-Chong, Khee-Meng is given as:

> Let $$\prod_{i=1}^rA_i=A_1\times\dots\times A_r=\{(a_1,\dots,a_r) | a_i\in A_i, i=1,\dots,r\}$$ denote the cartesian product of the finite sets $A_1,\dots,A_r.$ Then $$\left\vert \prod_{i=1}^r A_i \right\vert=|A_1|\times\dots\times|A_r|.$$

I want to know how this principle is applies in defining $P_r^n=n(n-1)\cdots2\cdot1$, ie, what are sets $A_1,\dots,A_r$ here?

Comment: Cartesian product is too restricitve.

Comment: Do you mean that this multiplication principle given in book is not enough for defining number of permutation and what we need is some generalization as in your answer?

Comment: Yes.  The cartesion product is insufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a procedure that can be done in $n$ steps and that

Step 1 can be done $s_1$ ways
Step 2 can be done $s_2$ ways no matter how the previous steps are done

....

Step n can be done $s_n$ ways no matter how the previous steps are done

Then the procedure can be done
$$\prod_{k=1}^n s_k$$
ways.